# Function that takes an array of numbers and returns a new one w/ smallest # in index 0 and largest # in index 1

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Working on exercises to build up my Javascript array skills.

Question is as follows: **Write a function biggest_smallest that takes an array of numbers as an input, uses .forEach(), and returns an array containing the smallest number in the zeroth position and the largest number in the first position.**

Instead of using forEach(), the only way I could think of doing this was as follows:

```js
var array_of_nums = [7, 8, 120, 60, 10]

function biggest_smallest(array){
  var new_array = []
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if (array[i] === Math.min.apply(Math, array)){
      new_array.unshift(array[i])
    } else if (array[i] === Math.max.apply(Math, array)) { ? }
  }
  return new_array
}
```

I'm not able to figure out how to place the largest number in index 1 (let alone refactor it using a forEach() method) to solve this exercise complete. I am assuming my method of placing the smallest number in index 0 is correct.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is supposed to work more or less like [`d3.extent`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_extent) I think the easiest option is just to iterate through with `Math.min` and `Math.max` checks:

```
function smallest_biggest(arr) {
    // ditch if no input
    if (!array.length) return [];
    // start with comparable values
    var extent = [Infinity, -Infinity];
    arr.forEach(function(val) {
        extent[0] = Math.min(extent[0], val);
        extent[1] = Math.max(extent[1], val);
    });
    return extent;
}
```

Underscore's `_.min` and `_.max` functions used to skip the first check, with the incredibly annoying result that `_.min([]) === Infinity`.

Comment: Pretty much this. Maybe you could have added what's wrong with his code (if there are multiple min elements he adds them multiple times, running complexity is `O(n^2)` etc.)

Comment: Thank you! Some of the code ( [Infinity, - Infinity] ) went a bit over my head, but the essence of using the forEach method to instantiate the zeroth and first position in the array was just what I needed. I'll go ahead and post my working answer, which I simplified a bit in order to wrap my head around for now.

Comment: Initializing with `[Infinity, -Infinity]` ensures that any check for min/max against a real array element will succeed the first time, because all numbers are less than `Infinity` and greater than `-Infinity`.

Comment: Ahh got it now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

**edit** My mistake, the question requires `forEach` iteration, so I suppose there *is* a need

There really is no need for iteration, you can just use `Math.min`/`Math.max`

```
function biggest_smallest(array){
   return [Math.min.apply(null, array), Math.max.apply(null, array)];
}
```

Comment: You're right, but his requirement was to do it using iteration.

Comment: I missed the `forEach` requirement, my bad. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Note also that `Math.min.apply(null, []) === Infinity`, for the same reason pointed out in my answer, which is :(

Answer (score 0):

I'd say first you need to find two variables: a (minimum value in the array) and b (the maximum).  Then, outside the loop (that you can implement using foreach or the regular syntax) you just push the two values to the resulting array:

```
new_array.push(a);
new_array.push(b);

return new_array;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array_of_nums = [7, 8, 120, 60, 10]

function smallest_biggest(arr) {
    var new_array = []
    arr.forEach(function() {
        new_array[0] = Math.min.apply(Math, arr)
        new_array[1] = Math.max.apply(Math, arr)
    })
    return new_array
}
smallest_biggest(array_of_nums)
```